# Virtual Button Functionality in AR Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to build an app in which camera will be always open and there will be list of buttons shown on the screen.
When the user clicks on the button, I want to call a function for that specific button.
Actually it is an augmented reality app.

When we have a target image then we can do such functionality with Vuforia SDK virtual button, but I want it without the target image.
How i can get this?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this UI buttons like a normal app do.
Also, you can use 3d objects and add funtionality to them, but be sure that you set the World Center Mode properly so you can see the objects.

Comment: i did not understand can you give me some example to understand it properly.thanks

Comment: Vuforia has a proprty called World Center Mode. This will determine the (0,0,0) world coordinates. You can set this to FIRST_TARGET, SPECIFIC_TARGET or CAMERA 
first target means that the first target detected will be your world center, so the other objects positions (like camera and other targets) will be setted depending on the first one (if you move the first target to the left, Unity will thake that as all the other targets move to the right)
specific target do the same, but you set the target you want to take as (0,0,0) instead of taking the first target found
Camera, you get the point

Comment: About UI buttons, you can use OnGUI function to draw buttons, or use a Canvas instead. 
[OnGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html)
or
[Canvas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQ2Qc_0MIyI)

Comment: the work i want to done is that  when the application launch the camera will be open and my element will be visible in the camera without scanning the target and from here when i click on some button then call its function.